# Establishin a relation between two tables without the primary key - foreign key relation (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following two tables:

ROOMS:

```
ID_Rooms PK number, 
RoomNumber number, 
COD_RoomType number, 
RoomPrice number,
Floor number
```

D_ROOMTYPE:

```
ID_d_RoomType PK number,
RoomType varchar2,
COD_RoomType number
```

The first table stores information about the hotel rooms, and the second one the codification for the room types (double room, triple room, family room, etc.). The data in the second table will be used to identify the room types in the first one.

I need to establish a relation between the two tables, but not based on the primary/foreign key relation, but on the COD_RoomType column which appears in both.

I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE rooms
ADD CONSTRAINT rooms_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (COD_RoomType) REFERENCES d_RoomType(COD_RoomType) enable;
```

but i get the following error report:

> Error report:
>  SQL Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary
>   key for this column-list
>   02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
>
> *Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
>              gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
>              key constraint in the referenced table.
>
> *Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
>              catalog view

Is there any method to establish a relation between the two tables on the COD_RoomType column without using the primary/foreingn key? If so what other modifications must I do and what will the SQL code look like?

Thank you,
Calin

Comment: @calin_bule You would need a third table to hold the `cod_roomtype` information, and then have a foreign key to that new table from both the `rooms` and `d_roomtype` tables. I'm not entirely sure why you'd want to do this, however - what's the link between room, room type and cod_roomtype?

Comment: (I should add that my suggestion to add a 3rd table assumes that the `cod_roomtype` column is not unique. If it is, then you can go ahead with Aleksej's answer below.)

Comment: Foreign key constraints don't relate tables, they enforce data integrity.  You can join the tables without a FK constraint.

Comment: @Boneist - i would prefer not to add a new table, i have enbough of them already :)

Comment: @reaab - I know tables can be joined without the PK-FK relation. I just want to link them somehow is such a way that it shows in the diagram of the DB I make with Oracle Data Modeller.

Comment: You may not have a choice if you want a well-designed, normalised schema. What is the meaning of cod_roomtype and how does it differ from id_d_roomtype. Is it unique in D_ROOMTYPE? If so, adding the unique constraint ought to do the trick, as per Aleksej's answer.

Comment: What column sets of a table hold unique subrow values? What subrows of one table must appear as subrows of another table (forming an "inclusion dependency")? You know what the rows mean and the possibilities that can arise so you need to tell us that. The only inclusion dependencies that SQL can declare are ones referencing a superkey (UNIQUE NOT NULL or PRIMARY KEY).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you need a unique constraint on the referenced table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE rooms
  2  (
  3      ID_Rooms        NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  4      RoomNumber      NUMBER,
  5      COD_RoomType    NUMBER,
  6      RoomPrice       NUMBER,
  7      FLOOR           NUMBER
  8  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE D_ROOMTYPE
  2  (
  3      ID_d_RoomType    NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  4      RoomType         VARCHAR2(100),
  5      COD_RoomType     NUMBER
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE D_ROOMTYPE ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_COD_RoomType UNIQUE  (COD_RoomType);

Table altered.

SQL> ALTER TABLE rooms
  2  ADD CONSTRAINT rooms_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (COD_RoomType) REFERENCES d_RoomType(COD_RoomType) ENABLE;

Table altered.
```

However, in most cases it would be better to add the FK based on the PK of the referenced table, instead of de-normalizing the code in the referencing table

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. It returns the same ORA-02270 error as before.